# How to create a string in javascript which i can Stringify()

Tags: javascript, json

I have a requirement like as follows :

I have productid and productname and then I want to create a object which on calling JSON.Stringify

showuld look like following

```
"[{"product_id":"123","name":"stack"},{"product_id":"456","name":"overflow"}]"
```

Is it possible to do in javascript...

Comment: So, what do you want? Create an object and stringify it? Or vice versa, get a string and then build an object from it?

Comment: @Saurabh: from where are you getting this `product_id` and `name`. thats what we would like to know

Answer (score 3):

```
var theObject = [ { product_id : 123, name : 'stack' }, 
                  { product_id : 456, name : 'overflow' } ];
```

or if you have the product ids and names in two arrays:

```
var theObject = [ ];

for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
    theObject[i] = { product_id : product_ids[i], name : names[i] };
}
```

Comment: how can i create this object if i have product ids and product name..?

Comment: @Saurabh: where is your product_id and name now?

Comment: How i create this object---- [ { product_id : 123, name : 'stack' }, 
                  { product_id : 456, name : 'overflow' } ];

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar: Well, he did write how to create it. Just copy any of 2 example codes and use it. Dont forget to accept the answer (press on big green "V" button)